# LabManager - Assigning "System Administrator" to a User - Possible?

Tags: permissions, vmware-vcenter

There are certain aspects of the LM UI that are available only to the System Administrator - is it possible to be assigned as a role to an LDAP, imported user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.  This is what I did using LM 4.

Create a group, in my case in Active Directory, I called it LM_gbl_admin.  Populate with users you want to be Lab Manager System administrators.

In LM make sure you select Global as the Organization. 
Select Manage --> Users and Groups in left sidebar.
Selet the Groups tab, Click the Import Groups... button.
Type partial name in search box, click search button.
check group name, click add button, select System Administrator in role drop down list.

Finally click OK.

If System Administrator doesn't appear in drop down list, verify you are in the Global organization.

Good Luck